# Angular 6 - Authentication admin user and root user

Tags: node.js, angular, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I created a MEAN stack application. I set up a user authentication with Passport module. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/).
This works properly.

However, I would like to add admin users and I would like some advices.
I thought about adding a parameter in my User model like this:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
  },
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  admin: {
    type: boolean,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  hash: String,
  salt: String
});
```

Is it a good idea or there is a better method ?

Comment: It just depends on the needs of your application but this is a totally valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah can be done via this way, usually what I've seen is they have an array of roles. A user may have different priveleges or more than one. Can be a User + Admin, or something else etc. Depends on the usecase.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that and use it as criteria for your Angular guards. When designing the rest of your app, remember your backend should never trust your client because it can easily be spoofed. Only the server should determine which roles are attributed to every authenticated user and give the right permissions to every endpoint of your API